# How to model attribute units in a database design?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, normalization, database-normalization

I need to design a database table where most attributes have units. For example:

```
Readings
--------

id   load (kW)   fuel_consumption (tonnes) - etc
1    1154        89.4
2    1199        54.2
```

What's the recommended way to capture the units in the design? For example, I could:

- **store units within attribute names** e.g. load_kW and fuel_consumption_tonnes
- **store units in a separate table** e.g. each value becomes a foreign key to another table with columns for value and unit.
- **store outside the database:** e.g. in business logic, or in documentation
- **are there others?**

I happen to be using MySQL, but I assume this is a generic database normalisation problem.

Comment: It might also be good to know if you only want to store basic units of the SI system and there scale or if there is also the need for combined units such as acceleration `m/(s^2)`. Then it might be a good idea to have a table that models the SI system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question...

There are two obvious routes:

```
id   load_kW     fuel_consumption_tonnes
--------------------------------------------------
1    1154        89.4
2    1199        54.2
```

This is easy for humans to read, and fairly logical. However, if some readings are in "kilos", others in "tonnes", you have to convert those readings to fit into the "readings" table; this process MUST be "lossless", and idempotent. For instance, a reading of "89403 kilos" is not "89.4 tonnes", even though the business may choose to round from kilos to tonnes for convenience. There are usually some counter-intuitive rounding things that happen...

If that's the case, you could change the schema:

```
id      load load_unit    fuel_consumption fuel_consumption_unit
--------------------------------------------------
1    1154  kW          89403              kg
2    1199  kW          54.2               t
```

With a "unit" table, if you need it:

```
unit_id    unit_name
--------------------
kg         kilogramme
t          Tonne
```

However, this model is open to human failure - it would be easy to change the "load_unit" column without modifying the "load" column, thus breaking the data. There's nothing you can really do to your data model to avoid this. It also makes common queries fairly tricky: imagine trying to retrieve the total of "load" in a consistent unit of measurement.

I would recommend that in this case, you have two tables: "raw_readings", with the original data in the format above, and "normalized_readings", which you populate by converting all the readings to a consistent unit of measurement.

Answer (score 2):

It depends ultimately on what you intend or need to do with your quantities.

If (in the unlikely case) all you will ever do is record the values for later regurgitation, then it doesn't really matter what you do with units, since the scalar values have no semantic significance to your model.

It is much more likely to be the case that the scalars in your system have some importance to your system.  This could be because you are performing calculations on them for example.  In such a case your units matter very much.

The next question you need to answer for yourself is whether the units will always be consistent and must not be allowed to be changed.  In most cases I would say that this is a risky conclusion.  It could be a business rule that you impose through your system, but business rules have a nasty habit of changing.

For this reason I would recommend storing a unit of measure with every scalar that represents an actual measurement.  Being explicit in this way takes a bit of disk space, but it gives you clarity and flexibility.

Something that I have done in the past is to extend the unit of measure model to include UOM types, like length, temperature, volume, time, etc.  Keeping a table that maps each UOM to a UOM Type allows you to also store conversion factors.  That way, if someone should come to you with a reading in BHP and pounds you would know what to do with it and how to compare it to your typical entries in kW and tonnes.